# Where to ask for source of a quote?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to figure out who said something so that I can quote them properly. I've googled the quote ("You can't take back the words you never said"), but I get no results of that quote. I got the idea for the quote from the song “Words I Never Said”.

Where should I ask that question? I feel like english.SE is probably the best bet but I'm pretty sure that isn't the scope of that site.

My question will basically ask this (but it would sound better)

---

I'm trying to figure out who said "You can't take back the words you never said", but I can't find any results online. I got the idea for the quote [from the song "Words I Never Said"](https://genius.com/109444) by Lupe Fiasco, but I changed it from "I can't take back the words I never said". Even then, I'm pretty sure Lupe Fiasco didn't write the song, so I don't want to quote him on it, and I don't want to quote Skylar Grey just because she sang that part of the song...

Maybe I'm overcomplicating this -- should I just quote "Anonymous"?

Comment: I don't think this is on topic on any site. "should I just quote 'Anonymous'" - that seems fine, but I'd probably instead opt for "as the saying goes, ..." (since you're presumably not 100% sure this was actually said by someone notable nor that you have the quote exactly right). If you want to know how to present the actual quote if you don't know the author, that could be on topic on [english.se].

Comment: That's just too broad for any SE site. If you can narrow it down, e.g. quote from a movie, you might find a site otherwise I'm afraid you're on your own here.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for your reply! I also just changed the title

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for your reply — in the bottom of the post (my “example” question), I included the song I got the idea of the quote from... I should have included that in my actual question, so I just updated the post.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to try to find the original author of a quote, come on over to [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com). We've got a whole tag dedicated to such questions: [quote-identification](/questions/tagged/quote-identification). So pop on over and we'll give it a shot!

If you know where the quote is from, though, that's probably not what we're looking for. I think that [MusicFans.SE](https://MusicFans.stackexchange.com) might accept such questions about who originally wrote the song, though I'm not certain. It looks like their tag [unknown-composer](/questions/tagged/unknown-composer) is for such questions.

Comment: The [help center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) confused me. It says that Literature.SE is the right place to ask if I can't remember the quote **itself**, but does not say anything about identifying the **source** of the quote.